# JavaCV FFmpeg ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, centos, javacv

Есть приложение которое пишет видео с rtsp потока. Проект собираю с помощью gradle. На локальной машине (там стоит kubuntu) все работает хорошо и верно. Как я отправляю свой `.war` на сервер(там стоит CentOS), то получаю такую вот ошибку

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil$AVFrame.

И на локальной и на удаленной машине стоит Tomcat. Пробовал собирать проект на другой машине с kubuntu и там тоже все работает без ошибок. В чем беда?

UDP: 
Ошибка  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так добавляю в `gradle` все зависимости.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И дерево с библиотеками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил какие библиотеки попадают в war. действительно класса `org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil` там нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? На двух машинах с `kubuntu` это работает.

#### UPDATE

Как я понял для CentOS надо самому собрать библиотеку. Делаю все по инструкции

[Building JavaCV on CentOS 6.5](https://github.com/montvieux/javacv-on-centos-6/blob/master/entry.md)

Но на шаге 9 получаю ошибку

9. Build the opencv profile only, and install into local maven cache

   mvn install --projects opencv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### UPDATE 2

Связался с разработчиком библиотеки. Он говорит что эта старая инструкция создания библиотеки и предложил новую.
[Инструкция](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Build-Environments)
Но получаю ошибку на шаге

> $ wget https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
>
> $ rpm --import https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Добавьте последнюю ошибку текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас всё та же проблема с javacpp. В ошибке явно написано, что `opencv2/core/types_c.h: File does not exist`.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `rpm -k --import https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern`

Answer (score 3):

[`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) всегда значит одно и то же: виртуальная машина не смогла найти класс, вызываемый по строковому представлению его полного имени.

В данном случае Java не может найти в `CLASSPATH` класс `org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil$AVFrame`. Убедитесь, что соответствующая библиотека (вероятно это [JavaCPP Presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets), от которой зависит JavaCV) попала в сборку.

Comment: Один и тот же собранный проект. На двух машинах с `kubuntu` работает как тадо. А на сервере, где стоит `CentOS`, такая вот ошибка

Comment: Я это понял. Но вы можете подтвердить, что в war-файл попал JavaCPP Presets?

Comment: смогу проверить только после выходных. И вроде как я перепутал исключение с `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` значит, что на момент компиляции класс был доступен, а при работе приложения - нет.

Comment: Я пробовал и собирать свой проект на сервере. `gradle` подтянул все библиотеки нужные для сборки. Но все равно не работает. Проверю в понедельник точно ли попадает класс в `CLASSPATH`. Но с другими библиотеками проблем нет.  например для отчетов в docx использую

 `compile('org.docx4j:docx4j:3.2.1')`, 

а для построения графиков

`compile ('com.xeiam.xchart:xchart:2.5.0')`

 и с ними проблем нет

Answer (score 1):

вроде для работы с javacv надо: 1) добавлять библиотеку OpenCV в ОС 2) добавить зависимость на JavaCV в мавен. JavaCV работает как обёртка для основной библиотеки OpenCV

Comment: и кажется OpenCV должна идти была из коробки Ubuntu-подобных систем, а в Cent Os я сам не разбираюсь